# Local files taking long time to open when connected to vpn

Tags: windows, file, vpn, explorer

Files in my windows-xp system are taking a long time (above 20 sec) to open when I'm connected to VPN. Same files open instantly when I'm out of vpn. I'm using Cisco VPN client.
One more observation is, even right click on files take unusually long times (close to 20 sec) to show the menu.
During this time explorer hangs and the hourglass appears in the explorer window where the file was tried to be opened or right clicked on.

Answer (score 1):

I used to have this problem sometime ago. This usually happens if you ever tried to use a resource such as printer or another computer on one network which is unavailable on the other network.

Windows stores this information somewhere and keeps trying to access that unavailable resource each time you right-click until the operation times out.

Try deleting any printer connections and mapped drives that may be unavailable from the VPN network.